# java swing component not showing up while loop

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I've been wrapping my head around this problem for a while now... can anyone help me?
I want the frame to show up when I press the button in button.java. However, because of the while loop, the frame does come up, but I cannot see the elements inside it.
I realize that the while loop needs to end before the components show up, but I need to check if a component has been modified.
Is there a way to not use the while loop to check if a component has changed? or is there a  way to display all the elements without erasing the while loop? Thank you in advance!

The code below is a simplified version of my code.

```
package problem;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

public class button extends JFrame {

   button() throws InterruptedException {

       JPanel panel = new JPanel();
       JButton start_button = new JButton("START GAME");
       start_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                   frame f=new frame();
               try {
                   new man(f);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

           }
       });

       panel.add(start_button);
       add(panel);
       setSize(1000, 300);
       setVisible(true);

   }
   public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException {
       new button();
   }
}
class man {
   int c=0;
   man(frame f) throws InterruptedException {
       while(true){
           while(f.a==0){
               System.out.println(f.a);
               if(f.a==1 && f.b==10) {
                   c=9;
                   break;
               }
           }
           //sleep(500);
           break;
       }
   }
}
class frame extends JFrame {
   int a,b;
   frame(){
       a=4;
       b=10;
       setTitle("frame");
       JButton b1 = new JButton("hello");
       b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
               a--;
               if(a==1) b=0;
               System.out.println(a);
           }
       });
       add(b1);
       setSize(300,300);
       setVisible(true);

   }
}
```

Comment: 1) Class names should start with an upper case character. 2) Variable names should be meaningful. Single character names mean nothing to us and we have no ideal what your code is attempting to do.  I have no ideas why you would have a while loop when attempting to create and display a frame. Your frame displays nothing.  If you need some kind of animation then use a Swing Timer.

Comment: `while(f.a==0)` This means that the loop will be entered **only if** `f.a` is zero. So the `if` statement inside the `while` loop doesn't make sense: `if(f.a==1` How can `f.a` equal one when it can only equal zero (according to the code in your question). Did I miss something in your code? In any case, if you want to open a second window, consider using [JDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) instead of `JFrame`.

Comment: I copied the code in your question. It compiles and runs. When I press the _START GAME_ button, another window is displayed that contains the _hello_ button. When I click on the _hello_ button, the value of `a` is decremented. Maybe I don't understand what you mean by _the frame does come up_. Do you mean that you don't see the window with the _hello_ button when you click the _START GAME_ button?